# Glyph origins of the character 拜

Tags: glyph-origin

I've seen somewhere that it was two hands together greeting someone. It makes some sense since the left part does look like 手, but the right part doesn't, and I don't remember any other characters that have it.

What's the real story about the character 拜?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「拜」was originally「」, comprised of「手・扌」and「」.

> 「」(please read this in both meaning and sound as「禱」) depicts *flowery adornments* used in dances and religious prayer/rituals.
>
> <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [佚](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)32
> [合集1439](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=1439&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 番生簋蓋
> [集成4326](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4326&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)61背</kbd>
> 　
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>

The combination of「手」(*hand*) and「」(*flowery adornments used in dances and religious prayer/rituals*) indicated the meaning *to conduct obeisance*.

<kbd>西周
金
[image]
沈子它簋蓋
[集成4330](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4330&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
簡
[image]
[睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)153</kbd>

In the character「」, the bottom part of「」was sometimes corrupted into something that looked like「手」.

<kbd>秦
簡
[image]
[日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)166</kbd>

Similarly, the top part of「」, which is「卉」, was sometimes removed. This leads on to the modern form of「拜」.

<kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
鄭固碑</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

---

**References**:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 1):

> http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/xs/62DC.htm
>
> (1) (会意。从两手,从下。《说文》古文上象两手,丅为“下”的古体。《说文》引 扬雄说:“拜从两手下。”表示双手作揖,或下拜。隶书将“丅”(下)并入右边的“手”之下而成为“拜”,一直沿用至今。本义:古代表示敬意的一种礼节。两手合于胸前,头低到手)

- 丅为“下”的古体 (丅 was 下 (down)'s ancient form)
- (下)并入右边的“手”之下而成为“拜” (下/丅 was merged into the right side 手)

Basically, The character '拜' depicts [two hands + move down] = [to worship --> to show respect] and it extended to more different meanings over time.